# PowerShell remote session and Start-Job issue

Tags: powershell, session, jobs, start-job

I am trying to run following script with job but the code in the block only executes 1st command and exits. Job is displayed completed on my computer

```
$computers = get-adcomputer -filter * | where { ($_.DNSHostName -match 'server')} 

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer.DNSHostName
        Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
            Stop-Service  W3SVC -Force
            Remove-Item "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root" -Force -Recurse
            Start-Service  W3SVC     
        } -asjob -jobname IIS_Maintenance
        Remove-PSSession -Session $session
}
```

If I comment out `-asjob -jobname IIS_Maintenance` job runs fine but it's synchronous. It takes several seconds to stop IIS but I am not sure why job is not waiting on that.

Thoughts?

Comment: `Invoke-Command -Computer $computers -ScriptBlock {...} -AsJob -JobName IIS_Maintenance`?

Comment: Are you just trying to do this async?

Comment: Argghhhh I just noticed I've put bad code, I started experimenting to figure out what's the problem... Correct code is:

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer.DNSHostName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ....

There is no start-job line. Yes, I am trying to execute this in async way so I can have X number of parallel jobs.

Comment: Instead of putting your code in a hard to read format in a comment you can edit your original post with your updated code.

Comment: Thanks Jason, code is now edited.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the session induces a lot of delay. Why did you chose to use the `-Session` instead of directly using `-ComputerName` ?

I think using the `-ComputerName` way will be more efficient to run with `Start-Job`. Either way, Since you are invoking the jobs on remote machines, your workstation would have no clue on the progress of the jobs.

If you want to track the progress of the jobs, you shouldn't be using `Invoke-Command` at all.

Comment: The reason for using session is because I need to execute several commands so it would seem more effective to open a session, execute several commands and then close the session. 

Also from the book "Learn Powershell in a month of lunches":
PS C:\> start-job -scriptblock { invoke-command -command { dir }
➥-computername SERVER-R2 }
That’s completely redundant; keep the Invoke-Command section and use the -AsJob
parameter to have it run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out... the point of confusion was:

1) I didn't know I can send block of code without Session and yes session implementation is slow

2) I also didn't know I send invoke-command to several computers are once without foreach. Thank you for that Ansgar Wiechers!